# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error when trying to make migrations.
Migration test_1.0001_initial is applied before its dependency test_2.0016_boolean on database 'default'.
I've tried python manage.py makemigrations --merge
I have also tried. python manage.py migrate --fake

Answer (score 0):

is this your production server? if not then try deleting all migration files and dropping migration table and re running makemigration cmd like this [Django 'migration is applied before its dependency' when running any migration commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621150/django-migration-is-applied-before-its-dependency-when-running-any-migration-c). when testing or developing that's how I always went around this error. but if your app is hosted or it is a production server then try these ways [Django manage.py: Migration applied before its dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996599/django-manage-py-migration-applied-before-its-dependency)
Also check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59884520/8363401 where author has explained the cause of these kinds of errors.

Comment: I have deleted  'test_1.0001_initial' then faked the migration `python manage.py migrate --fake` and it has worked

Comment: Glad it worked. Consider upvoting and accepting the answer which will allow other people to get help from here as well.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether there is any pending migrations using

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

if you found any pending migrations try normal migrations command if it doesn't works try the fake

```
python manage.py migrate --fake <your_app_name> <the_migration_name>
```

this could fix the issue I guess, if not then try deleting your migraions folder and DB then try again

Comment: Deleting the migrations then `python migrate.py makemigrations` worked perfectly !!

Comment: good to hear that it worked please give me an upvote to support